# Forward specific urls on same domain to different servers

Tags: iis, load-balancing, episerver, infrastructure

During a rollout of a large site (IIS, .NET, EPiServer) with multiple markets we want to forward markets to the new server when the market has been added to the new web platform, but we still want to use the same domain.

www.customer.com/marketA  -> old server, ip 1.1.1.1
www.customer.com/marketB  -> old server, ip 1.1.1.1
www.customer.com/marketC  -> new server, ip 2.2.2.2

What is best practice for this? 
Should we add a load balancer in front of the servers that based on the url sends the traffic to the correct server or is it possible to do this on dns level, or should we let all traffic go to one server and redirect the traffic with HTTPRedirect to the new server. Or is there any other alternatives?  (The rollout will take at least 6 month)

Comment: Perhaps this should go on Server Fault? More server/sys admins there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to rely on Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing